# How exactly does the Nernst equation account for temperature?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, electrochemistry, temperature, nernst-equation

I am doing an experiment that involves changing the temperature of the electrolytes in a voltaic cell and seeing the effect on the initial voltage produced. I'm a bit confused because if I use the same concentration of solution for each electrolyte, then $Q = 1$ and $\ln Q = 0.$

Then, you are simply left with $E_\mathrm{cell} = E_0.$ I read another post where it says $E_0$ itself is a function of temperature but I don't full understand how that works. Is there any way I can account for this in a high school lab environment?

Comment: Se also: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26405/why-does-temperature-affect-cell-potential

Answer (score 3):

There are two temperature dependences involved in the Nernst equation. The explicit one

$$\frac{RT}{nF}\ln{a}\tag{1}$$

and the implicit one

$$\begin{align}
E^\circ(T) &= \frac{-\Delta_\mathrm rG^\circ(T)}{nF} \\
  &= \frac{-\Delta_\mathrm rH^\circ(T) + T\cdot \Delta_\mathrm rS^\circ(T)}{nF} \\
  &\simeq \frac{-\Delta_\mathrm rH^\circ + T\cdot\Delta_\mathrm rS^\circ}{nF}, \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

where the TD variables assume the reaction

$$\ce{Ox + $\frac n2$ H2 -> Red + n H+} \tag{R1}$$

and the respective $E^\circ$ is for the half-reaction

$$\ce{Ox + $n$ e- -> Red} \tag{R2}$$

Standard reduction potentials  for nonstandard temperature are not usually available but for exceptional cases. Its change with temperature can be determined experimentally after subtracting the change of the the activity term. Theoretically it could be calculated if there is known or measured the standard reaction enthalpy.

The Nernst equation contains terms dependent and independent on activity. It is similar as for calculation of pH with terms dependent and independent on concentrations.

With a single potential, we would have $E(T,a)$. It is advantageous to have the term  independent on activity, as it is the specific parameter for the reaction. The single potential would not be and we could easily compare two half reactions.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Is there any way to determine the standard E at a given temperature then (either experimentally or literature values)? Also if the standard E is already affected by temperature, why is there another E in the Nernst equation? Is that not "doubling" the effect of it?

Comment: See the updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to study the effect of changing temperature[T] on the voltage of a galvanic cell. There are several factors to consider: First: the molar concentrations change with T. Second: The activities of ions vary with concentration and T. Third: There is a linear effect of T on EMF E[0]nF =-RTlnKeq. Fourth: Keq is a logarithmic function of T depending on the heat of reaction.

The first can be compensated by using the volume expansion of water. The second by researching activity coefficients. The third and fourth are what you hope to measure. Why the temperature dependence? Part of the energy content of the reactants is the thermal energy or heat; this is proportional to the absolute T. The rest is in the chemical potential energy difference in the bonds of the reactants and products. This is measured by the difference between the actual condition and the equilibrium condition. Why does the equilibrium constant change with T? When heat is added to a system at equilibrium the system changes in the direction that removes heat resulting in a new T and a new Keq. This is an application of LeChatlier's Principle.

A suggestion: For the reaction think about using a pH electrode with matching reference electrode. Solutions of known activities over activity and temperature ranges are available. The second study could be the equilibrium of pure water as a function of temperature. You will need a pH meter that reads in tenths of millivolts  and a way to determine the activity of H3O+ in pure water using the Nernst Equation.

Comment: An instantaneous own vote! What is going on here?

Comment: Thank you for your response! How does the concentration change with temperature? For my experiment, I am recording the initial voltage produced, so I would imagine the reaction doesn't have time to reach equilibrium. I will also be using low temperatures (less than 50 degrees celsius so I don't think it would evaporate). I'm not sure if I have access to a pH electrode or a pH meter (at least with that precision)

Comment: The potentials must be measured at zero current Use a good volt meter. Design the apparatus with minimum head space, plastic cling wrap will top evaporation. The density of water at the various T will almost correct for concentration changes. For temperatures might I suggest an ice bath, Zero Celsius, [273 K] An accurately measured ambient room temperature [~295K] and a hot water bath about 40 C [~315 K]. The exact Ts are not important . They must be measured precisely. Ask your teacher about the pH possibility it will be a good thing to have in the lab. Also you can work with activities.